# Java trying to use SuperCSV to take a string and create a pojo

Tags: java, csv, supercsv

I might be making this more complicated than it is but I have some code that gives me a CSV as a string.  I want to turn that into a pojo for some test code I am writing. I am using SuperCSV

```
beanReader = new CsvBeanReader(new FileReader(csvFileName),CsvPreference.STANDARD_PREFERENCE);
```

Seems that the only option is to pass in a file.  I would like to pass in my String.  Trying to avoid getting the CSV as a string, writing it to disk, reading it back in and making a pojo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you can use `new StringReader("a,b,c\n1,2,3\n4,5,6")`, give that a try.